# How to automatically detect the COM port being used by the arduino to pass data? C#

Tags: c#, serial-port, arduino-uno

I am using the Arduino Uno to communicate with my program in the C# Console, and I want the consolet automatically detect which COM port is being used to pass data and connect.
I've already managed to list all the COM ports does anyone know how to automatically connect to a COM port in C#?

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        _usbPort = new SerialPort();

        foreach (var s in SerialPort.GetPortNames())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s, "\n");
        }

       
        PortSerial();
    }
private static void PortSerial()
    {
        
        _usbPort.ReadTimeout = 2000;
        _usbPort.WriteTimeout = 2000;
        _usbPort.Open();
        
       
       // Write(1);
       // Read(2);
        Executar();
        
    }
```

Comment: There's no way to determine whether a COM port is connected without attempting to communicate with a device first. You would have enumerate the available COM ports until you successfully communicate with the device.

Comment: The normal way is to send a valid command and see if you get a valid response.  Often application automatically check baud rate by sending a test message at different baud rates and the seeing which rate gives valid response.